# How to write the time-dependent Schrödinger equation from generic functions?

Tags: wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, superposition, normalization

Given the initial state: $$\Psi(x,t=0)=c_1 \psi_1(x)+c_2\psi_2(x)+c_yy(x)$$ where $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ are eigenstates of $\hat{H}$ and $y(x)$ is a normalizable function but is not eigenstate of $\hat{H}$,  how the $\Psi(x,t)$ wave function could be written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since eigenfunctions of a Hamiltonian form a complete basis, you can always express every wavefunction as a linear combination of the eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian. So, you write $$y(x)=\sum_n a_n\psi_n(x)$$ and find the coefficients $a_n$ in the usual way, by exploiting the orthonormality of the eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr Dvij.
Generically, could it be written as $$\Psi(x,t)=c_1\psi_1(x)e^{-i\frac{E_1}{\hbar}t}+c_2\psi_2(x)e^{-i\frac{E_2}{\hbar}t}+c_y\sum_{n}a_n\psi_n(x)e^{-i\frac{E_n}{\hbar}t}  ?$$

Comment: @C.Monteiro Yes, precisely :)